# C# WebClient DownloadString suddenly gives timeout after months

Tags: c#, rest, timeout, webclient, downloadstring

About a year ago I made a tool to update our outdated Dell BIOS files automatically, but today it suddenly stopped working. I'm using the REST API the Dell site calls when surfing manually.

This is the request I send with the added header underneath:

```
GET http://www.dell.com/support/home/be/nl/bebsdt1/drivers/driverslist/platfromdriver?productCode=latitude-15-5580-laptop&osCode=WT64A
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

The strange thing is that it still works when using it with a request manipulator like HttpRequester (for firefox). I'm sure no other headers like UserAgent are sent.

The code in C# (with one model):

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest");
wc.QueryString.Add("name", "5580");
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += Wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.dell.com/support/home/be/nl/bebsdt1/drivers/driverslist/platfromdriver?productCode=latitude-15-5580-laptop&osCode=WT64A"));
```

I tested using Async or not, but for this issue it doesn't make a difference. A timeout is returned as an error.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is http://www.dell.com/support/home/au/en/aubsdt1/drivers/driverslist/platfromdriver?productCode=latitude-15-5580-laptop&osCode=WT64A&name=5580 downloading successfully for you from HttpRequester?

Comment: it gives me the data I need, so yes

Comment: How long does it timeout after? Does it work if you extend the timeout?

Comment: It doesn't work if I extend the timeout, Prateeks solution by adding the 2 extra headers helps for 2 requests but afterwards the timeouts start again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
var response = wc.DownloadString("https://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/inbsdt1/drivers/driverslist/platfromdriver?productCode=latitude-15-5580-laptop&osCode=WT64A&name=5580");
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Comment: Thank you Prateek, adding the 2 extra headers made the code work. But there is still an issue, after 2 requests this way the following result in a timeout as well. I need to do about 20. Any ideas to combat this? I will mark this as an answer if no extra ideas were found.

Comment: I edited the answer for asynchronous use, this solved the problem I was talking about in the comment above. Thanks for the help!